# What is the meaning of these datasheet dimensions?

Tags: circuit-design, connector, pins, dimensions, fpc

[image]

I am trying to buy a part for a project and I can't seem to understand what, ("B = A + 0.83[4.00]") means. Is this datasheet in mm or inches? Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like it is specified as inches [millimeters]

Answer (score 4):

You can use your real-world experience with units (or seeing which unit conversion is consistent) to know whether it is inches[mm] or mm[inches].

In this case it is *obviously* (if you have ever looked at a metric/imperial tape measure or rule) inches[mm] because 1 inch is humongous while 0.039mm is too small to see. Furthermore, \$0.039mm  \ne 1 inch\$ so the unit conversion is inconsistent, while \$ 0.039inches=1mm\$.

Comment: Amazing!, now I understand it.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the other answer, A is dependant on the number of pins, which is common in connector datasheets (the same datasheet is used for a series of connectors with varying pin numbers).

So A is 1mm * number of spaces between pins, B is A + 2.1mm, and so on.

So for a 4 pin connector, A is 3mm, B is 5.1mm, C is 7mm.

Comment: Thank you!, Now it is very clear